How to solve issue with HTML structure with auto expanding content height and parallax footer
I'm trying to make a structure with a auto-expanding content area overflowing the footer for a parallax effect.
However, I can't seem to find a solution that works 100%.
I end up having non-clickable links in the footer due to min-height: 100vh; on the <body>.
Is there a good way to solve this?


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 550px;
  background-color: #f90;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 1rem -1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 550px;
}
<header>Navigation</header>
<main>Content - auto grow</main>
<footer>Footer <a href="#">Link</a></footer>




The min-height on body isn't what's causing this, the z-index: -1 on the footer is. You're pulling the footer "behind" the body, so to speak, and therefor you can't interact with its content using the pointer device any more.

I have updated my post changing the z-index on the footer to 0. But then it overlaps my header.

So give the header a higher z-index then ...?

The footer height is 550px, setting s-index of header and footer to 0 and main to 1 can solve your problem.

You have set z-index: -1; of footer.
Making it 0 makes the link clickable.


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  background-color: #f90;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 1rem -1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
}
<header>Navigation</header>
<main>Content - auto grow</main>
<footer>Footer <a href="#">Link</a></footer>




Thanks, but it's still not quite solved.. I have updated my post changing the z-index on the footer to 0. But then it overlaps my header.

I have updated my snippet, please check and let me know what is required.

Yes, it works now, but it feels a bit odd to have to stack each element manually.

Then what is actually required? Please elaborate.
